# Is there a way to compose messages in thunderbird >= 8 with width 100 (or any other arbitrary value)

Tags: thunderbird

I find that when I paste excerpts from my text editor (width 100) into the thunderbird compose window it is truncated to width 80 or so by the time it gets to the receiver.  Within the compose window itself, there is no truncation.  I can verify this by sending the Email to myself.  I am not sure if these extra end of line characters/formats are inserted before sending or on receiving.  Is there a way to tweak this behaviour so that the width of my Emails are always 100?

Answer (score 4):

You can change the number of characters per line by changing the prefs value **mailnews.wraplength**. By default it contains the value 72.
Change it to 100 and plain E-Mail messages in the composer will be wrapped at column 100.

See also [Thunderbird Mail and news settings](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Mail_and_news_settings) and [Modify Thunderbird settings](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Modify_Thunderbird_settings).

The Config editor can be opened via:
**Tools → Options → Advanced → General → Config Editor**

Comment: Thanks for the link, though it seems to apply to an older version of Thunderbird. 8.0 version doesn't have tools->options menu and I can find no reference to a config editor for this version.

Comment: @SetJmp see my updated answer

Comment: @Serge Stroobandt: Which version of Thunderbird are you talking about. In Thunderbird 31.6 (Windows) the Config Editor is still available through the path mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @Robert In the GNU/Linux version of Thunderbird 31.6.0, the menu structure appears to be slightly different. Under Linux, the GUI path to open the configuration editor is: **Edit → Preferences → Advanced → General → Config Editor**

Answer (score 1):

One can even have the wrap length adapt automatically to the window width.
To do so, open the configuration editor (shown here for the Linux version of Thunderbird):

**Edit → Preferences → Advanced → General → Config Editor**

Then, set `mail.compose.wrap_to_window_width` to `true`.

**Caveat**

If you use Thunderbird with an [External Editor](http://globs.org/articles.php?pg=2&lng=en), then of course will need to properly configure that editor as well. For example: If you are a [Vim](http://www.vim.org/) user, you would add the following line to your `.vimrc` file to prevent default `textwidth` wrapping:

```
autocmd FileType mail setlocal textwidth=0
```

Comment: Thank you, had trouble finding `about:config`.